# VB.net MD5 command translation from C++

Tags: c++, vb.net, hash, md5, code-translation

I'm trying to write a code translation of a MD5 hash from C++ to VB.net but I am struggling to find the equivalent commands in VB.net.

Here is my C++ code:

```
md5_init(&md5);
md5_append(&md5, text1, 16);
md5_append(&md5, text2, 18);
md5_finish(&md5, digest);`
```

I am confused because md5 in vb.net does not have an append or finish function.

Comment: [`TransformBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`TransformFinalBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are probably the equivalent of `md5_append` and the [`Hash`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.hash%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property like `md5_finish`: [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: It would be more applicable to show your attempted VB code